# Selenium : How to click an element in the chat page whenever the new chat is available

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a chat page and need to click the chat whenever the chat appears. I am using a basic main method and I used this code `public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ravi\\Documents\\workspace\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new ChromeDriver();

     driver.get("https://demo.com/#!/login"); 
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='form.username']")).sendKeys("michea@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='form.password']")).sendKeys("143###");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
List<WebElement> sea = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='page']//div[@ng-click='selectSession(session)"));



}`
```

I know that list web elements is not a correct one and I know that I have use a for loop and if statement but I am so much confused..Please help me here Thank you in advance

Comment: You seem to not really struggle with Selenium concepts right now but more with basic Java things. I would suggest taking a step back and learning Java step by step first before you jump into a big and complex framework. You will probably reach your goal faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's better to use TestNg or JUnit annotation @Test and some public void method to write the test in it instead of main.
And it is hard to give you some advice without more explanation from your side about page structure.
The only thing I can suggest add some if statement where you can check if the chat is displayed or not, if YES click on it.

```
if(!driver.findElements(By.id("chat_id")).isEmpty()){
        driver.findElement(By.id("chat")).click();
    }
```

Comment: if this code is being run and as soon as you type anything in the chat box just a single letter the statements becomes true and clicks the send button. you might set a wait key for user to complete and then send.